# New branch from origin removed my unpushed commits

Tags: git, git-branch, git-checkout

I'm currently a bit in trouble.

I was having 3 commits on my master that I didn't push to `origin/master` yet, they were just lingering.

Now I needed a new branch from my `origin/master`.

I checked out `origin/master` and typed `git checkout -b [branch]`.

Now the 3 unpushed commits are gone!

Why is that happening?

Is there any way to get them back?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: They're not actually *gone*. They just became *hard to find*. There's something missing from the steps you listed, as you'd either have them on some other branch, or have gotten an error from that `git checkout -b` the way you showed it, but in any case, that's a general rule about Git: commits are read-only (always) and permanent (mostly: they evaporate if they're unfindable long enough), but if you can't find them, you aren't aware they're even there.

Comment: There was really no other step I made. Tho i didnt mention I was using UNGIT to checkout origin/master then made a new branch via terminal. I had no error in the console after using 'checkout -b'

Comment: Not sure what UNGIT might be, but that's probably the step that hid the commits away, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very strange situation. I don't know why it happened, but I suggest you to list all commits by `git reflog` and choose to reset to a starting commit has by `git reset <COMMIT_HASH>` or doing a `git cherry-pick <COMMIT-HASH>`.

Comment: Holy moly, that worked! Thanks a lot! I was able to find the hash and did git reset [hash]. The commits are back